# Linq 'Group by' after Migrate from Orchard 1.5.1 to Orchard 1.6

Tags: linq, nhibernate, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have a problem with 'group by'.
before Migration to Orchard 1.5.1, I didn't have any problem with this code:

```
var list = (from r in GetAll()
                    group new { r.FormulaCatId, r.InputPeriodId, r.CurrencyId } by new { r.FormulaCatId, r.InputPeriodId, r.CurrencyId }
                        into grp
                        select (new CatCurPerViewModel
                        {
                            FormulaCatId = grp.Key.FormulaCatId,
                            InputPeriodId = grp.Key.InputPeriodId,
                            CurrencyId = grp.Key.CurrencyId
                        }));
```

but after migration to Orchard 1.6 this problem occurred:

```
2013-01-10 15:01:25,704 [7] Orchard.Exceptions.DefaultExceptionPolicy - An unexpected exception was caught
System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
at NHibernate.Linq.CacheableExpressionNode.Resolve(ParameterExpression inputParameter, Expression   expressionToBeResolved, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.ExpressionResolver.GetResolvedExpression(Expression unresolvedExpression, ParameterExpression parameterToBeResolved, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.GroupByExpressionNode.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetResolvedKeySelector>b__0(ExpressionResolver r)
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.ResolvedExpressionCache`1.GetOrCreate(Func`2 generator)
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.GroupByExpressionNode.CreateResultOperator(ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.ResultOperatorExpressionNodeBase.ApplyNodeSpecificSemantics(QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.IntermediateModel.MethodCallExpressionNodeBase.Apply(QueryModel queryModel, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.ApplyAllNodes(IExpressionNode node, ClauseGenerationContext clauseGenerationContext)
at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.Structure.QueryParser.GetParsedQuery(Expression expressionTreeRoot)
at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at SAS.Core.Services.RateService.ListCatCurPer()
at SAS.Core.Controllers.RatesAdminController.Index()
at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass13.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__10()
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Comment: the problem is in this code:

    public IQueryable<RateRecord> GetAll()
        {
            return _rateRepository.Table;
        }

as you see I get data as IQueryable, I dont know why It works on 1.5.1 and didn't work on 1.6.
so I add '.ToArray()' in my code , the problem solved:

Comment: public IList<CatCurPerViewModel> ListCatCurPer()
        {var list = (from r in GetAll().ToArray()
                        group r by new { r.FormulaCatId, r.InputPeriodId, r.CurrencyId }
                            into grp
                            select (new CatCurPerViewModel
                            {
                                FormulaCatId = grp.Key.FormulaCatId,
                                InputPeriodId = grp.Key.InputPeriodId,
                                CurrencyId = grp.Key.CurrencyId
                            }));
            return list.ToArray();}

Comment: Well... "problem solved" with ToArray() means that you now load _all_ RateRecords from the database.

Answer (score 2):

the issue happens because in orchard 1.6 the Table property of Orchard.Data.Repository<T> is implemented in the following way:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get { return Session.Query<T>().Cacheable(); }
    }
```

and you cant use Group By with Cacheable() - [there is an open ticket in HNIbernate Jira](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2504)

Orchard does that Cacheable() call in order [to leverage 2nd level Nhibernate cache](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/orchard-cms-with-nhibernate-syscache2-database-caching).

If you do not use and do not intend to use this 2nd level cache and the corresponding module in Orchard, you can download Orchard source code, and change the implementation of the Table property in Orchard.Data.Repository<T> to

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get { return Session.Query<T>(); }
    }
```

This will fix your issue.

Or if you do not want to change Orchard sources, you can create your own generic repository class, and wire it up into DependencyContainer (by default Orchard comes with Autofac).
Here is how it can be done with Autofac 2.6.3.862:

```
public class MyRepository<T> : Orchard.Data.Repository<T> where T:class
{
    public MyRepository(ISessionLocator sessionLocator) : base(sessionLocator)
    {
    }

    public override System.Linq.IQueryable<T> Table
    {
        get { return Session.Query<T>(); }
    }
}

public class MyDataModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);

        Type limitType = registration.Activator.LimitType;
        if (!limitType.IsGenericType || limitType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof (Repository<>)) return;

        var epamRepoTye = typeof(MyRepository<>).MakeGenericType(limitType.GetGenericArguments());

        registration.Activating += (s, e) =>
                                       {
                                           var locator = e.Context.Resolve<ISessionLocator>();
                                           e.Instance = Activator.CreateInstance(epamRepoTye, new object[] {locator});
                                       };
    }
}
```

Probably (i have not tested this) the MyDataModule class can be simplified if you can guarantee that the assembly containing it will be loaded later than Orchard.Core assembly:

```
public class MyDataModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(MyRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerDependency();
    }
}
```